# Updating the selected dropbox item in a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

Currently I have a GUI in which once a 'Submit' button is pressed the drop menu which is left blank is then populated by a calculated value determined by the three other values.

[image]

I have successfully figured out how to grab all of the values using this logic:

```
temp=get(handles.FSTOPpopmenu,{'String','Value'});
fstop=temp{1}{temp{2}};
if (strcmp(fstop,'Select'))
    fstop = 0;
else
    fstop = str2num(fstop);
end
```

I just have two questions about this that I can not seem to find an answer for.

1. How would I go about updating the 'empty' drop menu to the calculated variable (the calculated variable will already be one of the possible values in the predetermined list)?
2. How would I go about presenting an error, say if I have an if statement checking that the amount of zeros in the array? Would a pop up box be sufficient?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As for your first question matlab's `set` command is what you're looking for. The documentation is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html). You would probably need:

```
MyValueIndex = find(DropDownValues==NewValue);

switch handleToChange

case handles.handle1 
     set(handles.handle1,'Value',MyValueIndex);

case handles.handle2 
     set(handles.handle2,'Value',MyValueIndex);

otherwise
     error('Uh oh!');
end
```

Note that `MyValueIndex` is the index of dropdown box values that you want. Which is found with a find command on the actual value.

Question two is more of an opinion question but I think that a pop-up box describing the problem is sufficient. Maybe add in a system beep for good measure!

Reference:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/22734-resetting-a-pop-up-menu-in-a-gui

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html

Answer (score 0):

1. For a popupmenu uicontrol the Value property determines which element of the String property is currently being displayed.  Get the String; compare its contents to the calculated variable to get the index; then set that index as the Value property.  If the calculated variable is not currently in the String then add it to the String and then set the Value.  (Note when comparing you need to compare numbers to numbers or string to strings, so you may need to do an appropriate data type conversion first).
2. Use an [errordlg](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errordlg.html).